# Calculate difference between values with same key index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

Hello: I have this DataFrame (sample)

| User | Timestamp | Production |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-01-01 | 5 |
| A | 2020-06-01 | 7 |
| A | 2020-12-01 | 15 |
| B | 2020-01-01 | 2 |
| B | 2020-06-01 | 7 |
| B | 2020-12-01 | 9 |

So, I need to calculate the difference between the values and append to the DataFrame. The resulting column i'm trying to obtain should be as follows: the production column for all the periods per user.
The resulting table would be as follows (production column omitted due to problem in table editor):

| User | Timestamp | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-01-01 | 5 |
| A | 2020-06-01 | 2 |
| A | 2020-12-01 | 8 |
| B | 2020-01-01 | 2 |
| B | 2020-06-01 | 5 |
| B | 2020-12-01 | 2 |

So i tried with the .diff() function but obviously it doesn't recognize when the index is different. I then tried with a groupby() applied on the user column to then compute the diff function, but I get the same problem:

```
df['Difference'] = df.groupby('User')['Production'].diff()
```

Can someone help me out?
Thanks!

EDIT:
Made a step ahead, but still trying to figure it out:
i wrote this:

```
grouped = df.groupby('User')
diff = lambda x: x['Production'].shift(+1) - x['Production']

daf['diff'] = grouped.apply(diff).reset_index(0, drop=True).fillna(df['Production'])
```

This does the difference the way I want It, but still messes up when the User identifier changes.

Comment: The `groupby` _should_ work, or at least work for everything but the first difference in each group. Is this not what you are seeing? Because the solution _should_ be something along the lines of `df.groupby('User')['Production'].diff().fillna(df['Production'])`

Comment: It works, but doesn't do what I'm trying to achieve: for example for the third row it does 7 - 15 and i'm trying to do 15-7. And for row 4 it does 15-2. But there I need just 2 because there is the change of User index.

Comment: Exactly write your expected result!

Comment: My expected result is written in the question, second table, column difference.